# How to deploy an ear in jboss from an URL?

Tags: deployment, jboss, jenkins, nexus

The more I read about deploying ears and wars on JBoss the more confused I become. Apparently the deployers change on every major version.

What I'd like to do is to define an MBean or whatever with an xml snippet in the deploy folder which tell JBoss6 to fetch an ear or war from a remote URL like a jenkins artifact url or from a nexus repository.

The background is to keep the big binary blobs out of our cfengine configuration repository. This also means that copying a new ear in the deploy folder does not work, because cfengine checks every hour and restores the config if it has changed. With the xml-config file, we can undeploy and redeploy through JMX to reload new test versions (which always are on the same url in jenkins) or from the released versions from nexus.

So does anybody know where there is an example of how to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Nexus?

Comment: During the build the ear or war is put in the nexus repository. The nexus repository exposes this as an URL. This is easy for release procedures because the release guardians only need to monitor the gates of the nexus repo.

Comment: Alright... Nexus exposes the components via http so nothing stops you from writing a bean that pull down ear or war from Nexus. However deployment of that will then probably be different based on app server . You might want to write an external tool that pull is down instead and the pushes it to the app server..

Comment: That's what I have done in the end. Thanks for the suggestions.